# Hosting Web API .NET Core v2.2 on IIS gives 500

Tags: iis, asp.net-core-webapi, asp.net-core-2.2

I'm trying to host my Web API built on .NET Core v2.2 on Windows 10 v1903.

I have the IIS installed, it's running.
I have installed the .NET Core Hosting Bundle.

I have copied over the output from the publish folder to a folder under inetpub/wwwroot:
[image]

I have created a website in IIS:

[image]

That website is using an application pool with "No managed code" CLR:

[image]

This is my web.config:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <location path="." inheritInChildApplications="false">
    <system.webServer>
      <handlers>
        <add name="aspNetCore" path="*" verb="*" modules="AspNetCoreModuleV2" resourceType="Unspecified" />
      </handlers>
      <aspNetCore processPath="dotnet" arguments=".\MyAPI.dll" stdoutLogEnabled="false" stdoutLogFile=".\logs\stdout" hostingModel="InProcess" />
    </system.webServer>
  </location>
</configuration>
<!--ProjectGuid: 3840a856-efc8-4efc-b593-556179293e4e-->
```

And it's giving me 500 Internal Server Error when I try to browse the site.

[image]

Logs:

```
#Software: Microsoft Internet Information Services 10.0
#Version: 1.0
#Date: 2020-02-04 01:32:33
#Fields: date time s-ip cs-method cs-uri-stem cs-uri-query s-port cs-username c-ip cs(User-Agent) cs(Referer) sc-status sc-substatus sc-win32-status time-taken
2020-02-04 01:32:33 ::1 GET / - 5050 - ::1 Mozilla/5.0+(Windows+NT+10.0;+Win64;+x64)+AppleWebKit/537.36+(KHTML,+like+Gecko)+Chrome/79.0.3945.130+Safari/537.36 - 500 19 13 514
2020-02-04 01:32:33 ::1 GET /favicon.ico - 5050 - ::1 Mozilla/5.0+(Windows+NT+10.0;+Win64;+x64)+AppleWebKit/537.36+(KHTML,+like+Gecko)+Chrome/79.0.3945.130+Safari/537.36 http://localhost:5050/ 500 19 13 0
2020-02-04 01:32:37 ::1 GET /swagger - 5050 - ::1 Mozilla/5.0+(Windows+NT+10.0;+Win64;+x64)+AppleWebKit/537.36+(KHTML,+like+Gecko)+Chrome/79.0.3945.130+Safari/537.36 - 500 19 13 0
2020-02-04 01:32:37 ::1 GET /favicon.ico - 5050 - ::1 Mozilla/5.0+(Windows+NT+10.0;+Win64;+x64)+AppleWebKit/537.36+(KHTML,+like+Gecko)+Chrome/79.0.3945.130+Safari/537.36 http://localhost:5050/swagger 500 19 13 1
2020-02-04 01:33:02 ::1 GET /myapi/swagger - 5050 - ::1 Mozilla/5.0+(Windows+NT+10.0;+Win64;+x64)+AppleWebKit/537.36+(KHTML,+like+Gecko)+Chrome/79.0.3945.130+Safari/537.36 - 500 19 13 0
2020-02-04 01:33:02 ::1 GET /favicon.ico - 5050 - ::1 Mozilla/5.0+(Windows+NT+10.0;+Win64;+x64)+AppleWebKit/537.36+(KHTML,+like+Gecko)+Chrome/79.0.3945.130+Safari/537.36 http://localhost:5050/myapi/swagger 500 19 13 2
2020-02-04 01:33:09 ::1 GET / - 5050 - ::1 Mozilla/5.0+(Windows+NT+10.0;+Win64;+x64)+AppleWebKit/537.36+(KHTML,+like+Gecko)+Chrome/79.0.3945.130+Safari/537.36 - 500 19 13 1
2020-02-04 01:33:09 ::1 GET /favicon.ico - 5050 - ::1 Mozilla/5.0+(Windows+NT+10.0;+Win64;+x64)+AppleWebKit/537.36+(KHTML,+like+Gecko)+Chrome/79.0.3945.130+Safari/537.36 http://localhost:5050/ 500 19 13 0
#Software: Microsoft Internet Information Services 10.0
#Version: 1.0
#Date: 2020-02-04 02:58:25
#Fields: date time s-ip cs-method cs-uri-stem cs-uri-query s-port cs-username c-ip cs(User-Agent) cs(Referer) sc-status sc-substatus sc-win32-status time-taken
2020-02-04 02:58:25 ::1 GET / - 5050 - ::1 Mozilla/5.0+(Windows+NT+10.0;+Win64;+x64)+AppleWebKit/537.36+(KHTML,+like+Gecko)+Chrome/79.0.3945.130+Safari/537.36 - 500 0 0 4473
2020-02-04 02:58:29 ::1 GET /swagger - 5050 - ::1 Mozilla/5.0+(Windows+NT+10.0;+Win64;+x64)+AppleWebKit/537.36+(KHTML,+like+Gecko)+Chrome/79.0.3945.130+Safari/537.36 - 500 0 0 5
2020-02-04 02:58:37 ::1 GET /MyAPI/swagger - 5050 - ::1 Mozilla/5.0+(Windows+NT+10.0;+Win64;+x64)+AppleWebKit/537.36+(KHTML,+like+Gecko)+Chrome/79.0.3945.130+Safari/537.36 - 500 0 0 4
2020-02-04 02:58:40 ::1 GET /MyAPI - 5050 - ::1 Mozilla/5.0+(Windows+NT+10.0;+Win64;+x64)+AppleWebKit/537.36+(KHTML,+like+Gecko)+Chrome/79.0.3945.130+Safari/537.36 - 500 0 0 3
#Software: Microsoft Internet Information Services 10.0
#Version: 1.0
#Date: 2020-02-04 02:59:15
#Fields: date time s-ip cs-method cs-uri-stem cs-uri-query s-port cs-username c-ip cs(User-Agent) cs(Referer) sc-status sc-substatus sc-win32-status time-taken
2020-02-04 02:59:15 ::1 GET / - 5050 - ::1 Mozilla/5.0+(Windows+NT+10.0;+Win64;+x64)+AppleWebKit/537.36+(KHTML,+like+Gecko)+Chrome/79.0.3945.130+Safari/537.36 - 500 0 0 1340
2020-02-04 02:59:18 ::1 GET /swagger - 5050 - ::1 Mozilla/5.0+(Windows+NT+10.0;+Win64;+x64)+AppleWebKit/537.36+(KHTML,+like+Gecko)+Chrome/79.0.3945.130+Safari/537.36 - 500 0 0 4
2020-02-04 02:59:27 ::1 GET /MyAPI/swagger - 5050 - ::1 Mozilla/5.0+(Windows+NT+10.0;+Win64;+x64)+AppleWebKit/537.36+(KHTML,+like+Gecko)+Chrome/79.0.3945.130+Safari/537.36 - 500 0 0 3
#Software: Microsoft Internet Information Services 10.0
#Version: 1.0
#Date: 2020-02-04 03:18:09
#Fields: date time s-ip cs-method cs-uri-stem cs-uri-query s-port cs-username c-ip cs(User-Agent) cs(Referer) sc-status sc-substatus sc-win32-status time-taken
2020-02-04 03:18:09 ::1 GET / - 5050 - ::1 Mozilla/5.0+(Windows+NT+10.0;+Win64;+x64)+AppleWebKit/537.36+(KHTML,+like+Gecko)+Chrome/79.0.3945.130+Safari/537.36 - 500 0 0 1836
2020-02-04 03:18:12 ::1 GET /swagger - 5050 - ::1 Mozilla/5.0+(Windows+NT+10.0;+Win64;+x64)+AppleWebKit/537.36+(KHTML,+like+Gecko)+Chrome/79.0.3945.130+Safari/537.36 - 500 0 0 5
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Please show the complete error page.

Comment: @LexLi updated with error page + IIS log

Comment: Assume that you have already resolved 500.19. The remaining 500.0 errors should be unhandled exceptions, so you need to enable specific logging https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/aspnet-core-module?view=aspnetcore-3.1#log-creation-and-redirection

Comment: No I'm actually stuck here real bad. I still can't figure out what's wrong with this application. I even tried creating a web API project using the template, deployed it, and it worked fine, although I'm using the exact same step.

Comment: Nvm, I found out the reason. It's not the API failed, the root cause is actually on Swagger. And Swagger didn't work because I never set the generate XML on Release configuration.

Comment: @Farid Please check full error message on the server. Could you please make sure that you have installed .net core hosting bundled?